# Explanatory 「の」 particle being used twice in the same phrase

Tags: particle-の, learning

I was reading [**Tae Kim's Guide to Learning Japanese** on the explanatory 「の」 particle](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/nounparticles#part5) and was following it very well. I was able to understand the usage of the **の** particle in the end of sentences to add an explanatory tone. Then, Tae Kim explained that it's possible to conjugate the **の** particle itself, creating the following:

- **んだ** (plain)
- **んじゃない** (negative)
- **んだった** (past)
- **んじゃなかった** (past-negative)

Although confused in the beginning, I believe I was able to understand that as well. *Except for one example:*

[image]

*(Taken from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=obOAAmHHHVI @ 08:12)*

**Let's look closely to sentence A.** *(I have no problem with sentence B, I left it there for completeness.)*

**Why Tae Kim needed two の particles (separately highlighted in red)? Shouldn't one suffice? Worse, isn't using two wrong?**

This seems like a double explanatory tone. In my point of view, the sentence A should be **日本 と 同じ なんじゃない** instead of **日本 と 同じ なんじゃないの**.

Comment: If you think 「日本 と 同じ( なん)じゃない?」and「日本のおすしは、もっとよかったよ!」would suffice, I quite agree. The use of の and なの here is what French call "tournure." (See the fourth bullet of this article -> http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/tournure/78756.)

Comment: I have no problem with the なの in phrase B nor with なんじゃない in phrase A, I like them to give the explanatory tone, but I still don't understand why Tae Kim felt like adding another の in sentence A, creating which seems to me a "double explanatory tone". I will edit my question to clarify. Also, sadly for me I don't speak french (yet!?).

Comment: I, too, have the impression that it creates a "double explanatory tone". All I can say is that can be her manner of speech. Maybe she thinks it makes her look more "feminine" to do so. (I dunno.)

Comment: Oh, I forgot. Never mind about Larousse. The article says "tournure" is a (sometimes idiosyncratic - caveat: this is my impression, not that of Larousse) way of usage of words and phrases in a statement.

Comment: @eltonjohn: thanks. It's good to know that someone else thinks the same. Hopefully there will be an explanation.

Comment: Agreeing with what @Darcinon said, I think your being a little too strict with grammar rules. Also the 2 の's have 2 different meanings. The first one (なんじゃない) means something very close to 'isn't it' and the second one adds a questionary nuance. So they are both very valid and also grammatically correct. As you read and hear more Japanese, you will realize that の carries a lot of nuances and is used in a lot of situations.

Comment: Indeed @RichardWatson, thank you. I understand perfectly now!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

じゃない as "isn't it?" is rather special because it can be appended to practically anything and still be grammatically correct. Also, the two locations of の are serving different purposes. 同じなの is giving the explanation of being the same (Tae Kim would probably translate it as "the thing is, it's the same"), and じゃないの is making じゃない less rhetorical and more inquisitive.

Repetition of concepts doesn't necessarily make things grammatically incorrect either. Consider the English phrase, "It is, isn't it?" which brings up another point - casual spoken language is much less strict with grammar than essays/formal writing, and Tae Kim is demonstrating casual spoken language with that example. In that case, the best measure of correctness would be a native speaker's approval.

Answer (score 1):

の and its shortened version ん work in Japanese usually at the end of sentences, as a subjective modifier. Example:

> 日本と同じです
>
> It is the same as in Japan.
>
> 日本と同じのです
>
> I don't know if it is the same in Japan, but at least from my point of
>   view, I see it as being the same in Japan.

Comment: Are you aware that 「日本と同じのです。」 means 「日本と同じものです。」? The の in 同じの is [の❺準体助-#2](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/171157/m0u/%E3%81%AE/) Edit: Oh, did you mean to type 日本と同じなのです?

Comment: You are right I though it was the same with sentence "B'. "A" sentence is a nominalization and "B" sentence is subjective modifier.

Comment: Hmm... are you aware that 日本と同じ**の**です。(casual) ≒ 日本と同じ[物]{もの}です。(formal) means "It's the same ONE as in Japan", "It is the same THING/ITEM as (the one) in Japan"? These are different from 日本と同じです or 日本と同じなんです/なのです.

Comment: Yes I do understand, I gave a failed paradigm where I modified given sentence A in a wrong way (the way I thought I read it).
I would only add that 日本と同じ物です does not exactly mean "It's the same ONE as in Japan", as far as I know it is still a subjective clause ( "To my understanding, it is the same one as in Japan, but that might not be the case"). The same way that もの is more subjective than こと and が is harsher than は. Please elaborate if I'm understanding something wrong.

Comment: Are you saying in your answer that the sentence 「日本と同じ**の**です」 would mean "I don't know if it is the same in Japan, but at least from my point of view, I see it as being the same in Japan.", rather than "It's the same ONE/THING as in Japan"?

Comment: And, are you really saying 日本と同じ**物**です doesn't mean "It's the same ONE/THING as in Japan", but "To my understanding, it is the same one as in Japan, but that might not be the case"? How would you say "It's the same ONE/THING as in Japan" in Japanese, then?

Comment: OK I've found where I'm losing you :)
I do not understand the way you use もの. I did some digging up in some grammar leaflets my tutor gave me and it says about 形式名詞ー物:
This noun, as a formal noun, shows metaphorically the "subjective truth/right situation that the speaker believes in". 
So basically, you might be talking about the plain word "物'' and I about the formal noun 物. Is this the case?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think you understand. I think you're confusing 日本と同じ**の**です(同じ + nominaliserの + copula) and 日本と同じ**なの**です(同じ + な(assertive auxiliaryだ) + intensifier/explanatory particleの + copula). 同じ**の**です means 同じ物です, "the same thing as." 同じ**なの**です is like "In fact, it's the same." We don't say 日本と同じのです or 日本と同じなのです to mean "I don't know if it is the same in Japan, but at least from my point of view, I see it as being the same in Japan." If you still have doubt please post it as a new question on the site and ask for other people's opinion.

Comment: No, I undestand what you are saying. I just thought you used もの a different way. Example:
子供はゲームが好きなものだ。
What does this mean? To my understanding, that means "Generally, I believe that kids like playing games" not "Kids like playing games". 
Thank you anyway for your patience and understanding!

Comment: I am sorry but this does not answer my question. I am aware of the の particle in end of sentences to add an explanatory tone. My question is why the **double** explanatory tone: once in **なんじゃない** and again in the ending **の** (both in sentence A). Also, as @Choko mentioned and I agree, I believe you forgot a **な** in your second example anyway.